# Rails 3: User input escaping working differently in views and mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, xss, actionmailer, actionview

I'm using the following set of code in both my views and the mailer:

```
<%= simple_format(auto_link(h(user_input))) %>
```

I begin by calling html_safe (h) on the user_input, in order to escape any dangerous code. I then call auto_link to enable any links in their input, and then I call simple_format to enable line breaks and such.

This works perfectly in my view, and properly displays the following, fully escaped, yet with a working link:

```
" http://google.com "
```

However, when the exact same is displayed in an ActionMailer email, I'm seeing all of the special characters, including my autolink, doubly escaped (the `&amp;quot;` for example doesn't display correctly as a result) :

```
&amp;quot; &lt;a href=3D&quot;http://google.com&quot;&gt;http://google.=com&lt;/a&gt; &amp;quot;
```

For some reason, I need to re-mark it as html_safe again to get it working:

```
<%= simple_format(auto_link(h(user_input))).html_safe %>
```

This correctly outputs:

```
&quot; <a href=3D"http://google.com">http://google.com</a> &quot;
```

**Any ideas on why ActionView and ActionMailer treat the same code differently?**

Comment: @mu is too short My email template file is called notify.html.erb

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you call simple_format from the email template (to render out line breaks), the behavior you get is terribly unusual, and it turns out this helper is overwritten with a private method.

Anyways, you can access simple_format in the email template by using this hack:

```
ApplicationController.helpers.simple_format()
```

Hopefully in another rails release this will be fixed.